# Do a find on the latest N items from tables X, Y, and Z sorted by date created?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to do a find on 3 different database tables using CakePHP.

favorites
comments
listings

Each table has it's own schema with id, created, modified, and some other fields. I want to do a find on all 3 combined sorted by the created date. So essentially...

```
[0] => array(
    [Favorite]
),
[1] => array(
    [Comment]
),
[2] => array(
    [Favorite]
),
[3] => array(
    [Listing]
)
```

Assume these are sorted by the created field which is a DATETIME in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) operator like so:

```
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT id, created, modified, "Favorite" as ST FROM Favorite
  UNION SELECT id, created, modified, "Comment"  as ST FROM Comment
  UNION SELECT id, created, modified, "Listing"  as ST FROM Listing
) 
WHERE ....
LIMIT ...
;
```